# There is an error when i would to run php artisan serve

Tags: laravel

Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\local/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\local\server.php on line 21

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\local/public/index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\local\server.php on line 21

This is what's inside the server.php file

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\ProcessUtils;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Process\PhpExecutableFinder;

class ServeCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'serve';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Serve the application on the PHP development server';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        chdir('/');

        $this->line("<info>Laravel development server started:</info> <http://{$this->host()}:{$this->port()}>");

        passthru($this->serverCommand());
    }

    /**
     * Get the full server command.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function serverCommand()
    {
        return sprintf('%s -S %s:%s %s/server.php',
            ProcessUtils::escapeArgument((new PhpExecutableFinder)->find(false)),
            $this->host(),
            $this->port(),
            ProcessUtils::escapeArgument(base_path())
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the host for the command.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function host()
    {
        return $this->input->getOption('host');
    }

    /**
     * Get the port for the command.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function port()
    {
        return $this->input->getOption('port');
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command options.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return [
            ['host', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The host address to serve the application on.', '127.0.0.1'],

            ['port', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The port to serve the application on.', 8000],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your laravel installed?

Comment: In the htdocs of xampp

Comment: when you `php artisan serve` it will run the php built-in server, so you do not need to use xampp, maybe stop the xampp apache server and try?

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: have you tried to install laravel somewhere else that is irrelevant to xampp, maybe try to install at the desktop for testing?

Comment: how is that? im not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Change what's in your server to this

Comment: And where is this file located?

Comment: In your root folder. below phpunit.xml. You will find server.php. If it's not there, create one and put the code above in it.